# ASP.NET Core - User Secrets per Git Branch

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings, user-secret

Is it possible to have different sets of `user-secrets` per git branch?

So that when switching from *feature-branch-1* to *feature-branch-2* you would pick up different sets of configuration? (ConnectionStrings, etc)

It seems like a fairly common use case, but I can't find anything branch related in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows)

Comment: user-secrets are not suppose to be added to git that's why nothing is mentioned in the document. infact the whole point of creating secret manager was based on that we should not add secrets to git. if you still want to add secrets in git then add those things in appsettings.json itself.

Comment: Sorry, I've obviously not explained myself brilliantly. I wanted to pick up different sets of secrets data depending on the name of the currently checked out branch, not store the secrets in the branches. Nothing I've seen suggests this is actually possible, but I just thought I'd chance my arm here